# Rails MetaSearch can't use or statement to combine 2 condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

Currently I'm using metasearch gem and I can't figure out how to add 2 conditions for one element in the search form.

Here is my code

```
f.select :market_product_status_equals, {}.tap { |h| 
  MarketProduct.status.each { |key,value| 
    h[key]= value
  } 
}, :include_blank => true
```

I wanted to have `market_product_status_equals` or `:market_product_status_is_null`

I tried doing this

```
f.select :market_product_status_equals_or_is_null, {}.tap { |h| 
  MarketProduct.status.each{ |key,value| 
    h[key]= value
  } 
}, :include_blank => true
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. how much code to do this!!! You can get a hash from an array very easily:

   ```
   f.select :market_product_status_equals, Hash[MarketProduct.status], :include_blank => true
   ```
2. If the available matchers do not fit your needs, just define your own, as in http://erniemiller.org/projects/metasearch/#customizing